# Simple binary to decimal converter - Issue in C#

Tags: c#, loops, while-loop, int

I've made a simple binary to decimal converter, used to work fine, I used a string variable to declare the values, but now realise I will need to store them as integers as I wanted to add in a while loop structure to validate the users choice so they could only enter 0 or 1's.

But I now have a program which says `Cannot convert from 'int' to 'System.IFormatProvider'`.. As I am a beginner with C#,

I have no idea what this means, and how to over come the problem, any help appreciated.. Here is my code if anyone wants to look at it:

```
        int iBinaryNum; //To store binary number
        int iDecimalNum; //To store decimal numbers

        //Validation of user choice & main program
        while (iBinaryNum == 0 || iBinaryNum == 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the binary number you want to convert to decimal");
            iBinaryNum = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            Console.WriteLine("The Binary number you have entered is " + iBinaryNum);
            iDecimalNum = Convert.ToInt32(iBinaryNum, 2);

            Console.WriteLine("This converted into decimal is " + iDecimalNum);
        }

        //If it's not equal to 0 or 1
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid binary number, Please re-enter");

        //Prevent program from closing
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to close");
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Your code doesn't make sense.

Comment: Why not? Worked fine before, I used to have iBinaryNum as a string (sBinaryNum) and it worked fine, but I need to validate the users choice, so I thought maybe converting it to an int would allow me to do it? So which part doesn't make sense?

Comment: i don't think you need while loop here, you can use if and then invalid console message statement should be in else block

Comment: @Sudhakar Yeah, I could do that, wouldn't really make a difference though? I'll give it a go after, I need to get this line fixed first "iDecimalNum = Convert.ToInt32(iBinaryNum,2);", just unsure how, I don't greatly understand what people in the answers are trying to tell me, I'm new to programming you see

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Complete Solution:**

You can Use `Regular Expressions` to Check for Particular `pattern` in the `Input String`

The following `program` will take the `Binary` input from user and converts it into the `decimal` till the invalid value is found

```
       string strBinaryNum=""; //To store binary number
       int iDecimalNum; //To store decimal numbers
       System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex r = new System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex("^[0-1]+$");
            
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the binary number you want to convert to decimal");
        strBinaryNum = Console.ReadLine();
        while(r.Match(strBinaryNum).Success)
        {        
        Console.WriteLine("The Binary number you have entered is " + strBinaryNum);
        iDecimalNum = Convert.ToInt32(strBinaryNum, 2);            
        Console.WriteLine("This converted into decimal is " + iDecimalNum);

         Console.WriteLine("Enter the binary number you want to convert to decimal");
         strBinaryNum = Console.ReadLine();
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to close");
        Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Yeah Thanks, I'll sort that out after, just really need to solve this int problem at the minute, Any chance you could explain in better terms what the others mean? Thanks :)

Comment: @user2985995: sure i will help you but as a first point your iBinaryNum contains binary value right? ex:1100111 , right?

Comment: Yeah, the user enters a binary number which gets stored in iBinaryNum

Comment: in that case your while loop might fail in most of the cases as user can only enter either 0 or 1 but not 10,011,1100 some thing other than 0,1 it would be failed.

Comment: Yeah, if I implement the IF Else statement, would it fix the problem ?

Comment: No, though you change the block the condition remains same so  it would be failed. let me give a try

Comment: Okay thanks, was thinking maybe "" if (iBinaryNum != 0 || iBinaryNum != 1)"" - Would probably solve it? But then going back to my main issue, I can't find a solution to it ?

Comment: I think the while loop was intended to keep prompting the user until the requirements have been met.

Comment: @Locke Yeah it was, But I realised now it won't work, But i'm not too worried about that issue, I can easily work on that and fix it myself, I need a fix to the first problem I listed

Comment: Check out the while loop I just provided and let me know if that meets what you're looking for

Comment: @Sudhakar Yeah I've got similar to that on my other program, works well if its a binary number entered, but I need the validator in place too, I'll give Lennarts solution a try in a minute, see if that help, thanks again.

Comment: Regex is a good choice.  Should be pretty fast too if you had to run a large group of numbers through it as well.

Answer (score 2):

```
iDecimalNum = Convert.ToInt32(iBinaryNum, 2);
```

The arguments you passed are `int, int`. As you can see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130995%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you can either choose between `Object, IFormatProvider`, `String, IFormatProvider` or `String, Int32`.

Since the first int can only be used as `Object`, this means the second argument has to be `IFormatProvider`.

If you want a solution, you'll have to clarify what it is you're trying to do. Why do you want to convert an integer to an integer?

Comment: I'm not really sure, I'm a big noob at C#, I got told that's how I'm meant to represent integers, starting by converting them, and then later using them.. So I'm guessing this is wrong? I just want to be able to convert binary numbers into decimals, which worked fine using a string, but the problem occurred as I couldn't use operators such as "||" in strings, any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`Convert.ToInt32(String, Int32)` requires the first argument to be a String and the second an integer. You are passing two ints, which resolves to `Convert.ToInt32(Object, IFormatProvider)` which generates the error. You have to convert the first argument (`iBinaryNum`) to a String.

But I don't think your code works as you expect, since the while condition only checks if either of the ints is either 1 or 0. If the user enters `1110` it fails. Also, if the user enters anything above Int32.Max (which wouldn't be too surprising, considering how large binary numbers can grow), your program crashes. I would store the user input in a string again and check each character whether it contains valid characters (1 or 0).

Like this:

```
bool IsBinaryNumber(string test){
        foreach(char c in test){
            // If c is not either 0 or 1, break.
            if(!((c=='0') || (c== '1'))){
                return false;
            }
        }
        // If everything went well, it's a binary number.
        return true;
 }
```

Comment: Alrite thanks a lot, I'll give that a go now, I see where your coming from, I'll have a look into this "String.Contains()" method, never heard if it before, thanks.

Comment: @Lennart: i don't think only checking for o's or 1's does not solve the problem using Contains() method as it would be succeded if the input string contains something like 0178,and surly its not a valid binary please correct me if im wrong.

Comment: This seems like the best option to me.

Comment: Yeah, I think it is, just trying to implement that into my code now, Thanks everyone for the help, Appreciated

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the different overload of [`Convert.ToInt32`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.toint32.aspx), you will see there are none that take as parameters `Int32, Int32`.

The overload resolution will select the one that takes `object, IFormatProvider` instead and `2` is an `Int32`, not a type that implements `IFormatProvider`, hence the error.

It is not clear why you are trying to convert an `Int32` into an `Int32` - you already have the value in `iBinaryNum`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I really understand the problem.  However here is a loop that will keep the only continue once the binary number requirements have been met.

```
uint iBinaryNum = 2; //To store binary number
decimal iDecimalNum; //To store decimal numbers

//Validation of user choice & main program
while (iBinaryNum > 1)
{
    Console.Write("Enter the binary number you want to convert to decimal: ");
    if (!uint.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out iBinaryNum) || iBinaryNum > 1)
    {
        //If it's not equal to 0 or 1
        Console.WriteLine("Invalid binary number, Please re-enter");
        iBinaryNum = 2;
    }
}

iDecimalNum = Convert.ToDecimal(iBinaryNum);
Console.WriteLine("This converted into decimal is " + iDecimalNum);
```

Comment: Oh, I think I completely missed what you are trying to do.  So you're trying to convert something like 11001001001 to it's regular numerical equivalent?

Comment: Yeah just to like a decimal number, for example 111 would be the binary equivalent for 7 etc.